# The kernel and range of the powers of a self-adjoint operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $L: V \rightarrow V$ self-adjoint (on a finite-dimensional space $V$); $b$ is a real number. Show

1. The minimal polynomial has distinct roots;
2. $\ker(L) = \ker(L^k)$ for $k\geq1$;
3. $\operatorname{im}(L) = \operatorname{im}(L^k)$ for $k\ge 1$;
4. $\ker(L-bI) = \ker((L-bI)^k)$ for $k\geq1$;

---

My thoughts:

1) I think I'm supposed to assume root is repeated and reach a contradiction but I'm not sure how to proceed mathematically with that.

2-4) pretty sure there's some huge theorem that I'm missing.

Comment: in 3) I presume you mean $k\geq1$ instead of $k\geq k$, right?

Comment: @DavidH Yes and fixed.

Comment: Do you know the spectral theorem? Among other things, it says that a self-adjoint operator is diagonalizable, i.e., that there is a basis of eigenvectors (in fact, we can choose that basis to be orthonormal).

Comment: @user49048 not supposed to use the spectral theorem :(

Answer (score 2):

Here's part 2. As you can see the style argument is almost disappointingly simple once you get the hang of it. See if you can formulate similar arguments for 3) and 4).

Pt.2) Suppose $v\in\ker(L)$. Then by definition of kernel $Lv=0$. Operating on both sides by $L$ gives:

$$L(Lv)=L\cdot0\iff L^2v=0,$$

implying $v\in\ker(L^2)$. Thus, $\ker(L)\subseteq\ker(L^2)$. To show the converse inclusion we'll need to invoke the assumption that $L$ is self-adjoint. Suppose that $v\in\ker(L^2)$. Then by definition $L^2v=0$. We want to show that this implies $Lv=0$. Recall a vector in an inner product space is the zero vector if and only if its inner product with itself is zero, and that the inner product of any vector with the zero vector is zero. Then,

$$\langle Lv,Lv \rangle=\langle v,L(Lv) \rangle~~\text{(def. of a self-adjoint operator)}\\
=\langle v,L^2v \rangle\\
=\langle v,0 \rangle\\
=0.$$

This establishes the equality $\ker(L)=\ker(L^k)$ for the base case $k=2$. The general case for $k\geq 1$ then follows by induction.